# How to prevent the system kill my 'foreground' service?

Tags: android, service, process, kill, foreground-service

I'm building an application similar to Runtastic/Endomondo/Strava, which needs a service getting GPS locations until the user stops it explicity.

I ran Runtastic and my app to try it. Runtastic worked fine. But my app, looses all data altought the notification was in the status bar yet. I think the service restart itself, or Android kill my service.

I tested the app in a LG G3 with 2GB of RAM, which I consider it's enought to run Runtastic and my app.

So, my question is **¿what is the best way to keep a service running in background, or avoid the system kill it?** I want to emulate the logic of Runtastic/Endomondo/Strava. That means, it doesn't matter the battery life.

- I've tried start the service with `START_STICKY` flag on method `onStartCommand`.
- I've tried to start service with `startForeground` method
- I've tried aquire a `WakeLock`

Following the documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html) my service should be 'A visible process'.

Here is a gist of my service's code: https://gist.github.com/cpalosrejano/cc1ab73c4819c3e84234f2d619421b93

¿Should I declare the service as process in Manifest.xml?

Comment: `startForeground ` should do the trick if you implement it correctly

Comment: @VladMatvienko I already use it. But my service being killed by system. Please can you give it a look to gist? Maybe I'm committing a mistake. Thanks anyway!

Comment: ok, it doesn't show how you start your service

Comment: @VladMatvienko My apologies. I just add the FragmentMain code, where I start the service.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the best way to keep a service running in background, or avoid the system kill it?

You don't. A foreground service is the best that you can get.

> But my app, looses all data altought the notification was in the status bar yet

Save your data to a database, `SharedPreferences`, files, or a server. A process is not a persistent data store.

Comment: I already save the data in database when user stops the service. The main problem is the service is being killed by system, which is causing the loss all variables of my service before the user stop it explicity. So, I need to keep the service awake until the user decides to stop it.

Comment: @cpalosrejano: "I already save the data in database when user stops the service" -- that is far too late. Save the data when the data changes, possibly in batches. " I need to keep the service awake until the user decides to stop it" -- no, you need to save the data as the data changes.

Comment: So, a foreground service is the best that I can get. That assures me the service doesn't get killed until the system run on low memory, isn't? If it is, I should avoid save variables on my service, to avoid consume memory. Thanks!

Comment: @cpalosrejano: "That assures me the service doesn't get killed until the system run on low memory, isn't?" -- no, but it increases the expected lifespan of your process.

Comment: Hi again @CommonsWare. I tried to make a empty service, with a wakelock and startForeground, and it still is killed by system. Give it a look here if you can, please: stackoverflow.com/questions/44065485/why-my-service-is-killed-by-system/ I know I should be anything bad, because if runtastic can run his service always, while my service is killed! Please help me!